# need to be able to find which records have notes & attachments

Tags: reporting, attachment, notes

I have searched the web with no success of finding a solution for this yet. How can I report on an objects records to find which ones have notes and attachments?

Comment: How many attachments do you have in your org ?

Comment: does it matter? it could be 100's or 1,000's I'm not sure.

Comment: ok i have a solution provided your attachment count is less than 50K .

Answer (score 2):

```
Select parent.type, count(id) from note group by parent.type
```

You can execute this from the developer console, workbench, data loader, a Visualforce page, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> If your attachment count is less than 50K then the following should help

```
List<Attachment> lst=[Select Id,ParentId,Parent.Type from Attachment ];
Set<String> setObj=new Set<String>();
for(Attachment att:lst){
   setObj.add(att.Parent.Type);
}
system.debug('OBJECT SET'+setObj);
```

> If its more than 50k then i would use query more and generate same or use a VF in read only mode and run the same program .Or probably use OFFSET to keep  building this set .

Probably we need same type of query on Notes as well to generate our object SET .

Comment: should I build a page and use that code in it? Can you give an example/illustration of how it would work?

Comment: You can use a VF and Pass the SET in a list as Getter and Setter.The log would give you all objects that has notes and attachment anyways